# Save a calculated result in a table using a query (Access 2007)?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a form of multiple project sites where one of the fields is labelled "Project Start Date". I have another field in the form labelled "Projected Project Finish Date". Both fields are stored in a table labelled "General Project Info" (well, at least that's the source of the information for the form come from).

I could manually fill in the Proposed Project Finish Date by adding 10 days to the Project Start Date, but I would like to make it a calculated field, i.e once someone puts in the Project Start Date Access automatically calculates the Proposed Project Finished Date.

I am aware you can use a query to calculate this: New Query-->Include Project ID and Project Start Date fields, then make the third field--> Proposed Finish Date: DateAdd("d",10,[Project Start Date]). This produces a query result which has a column with all the sites, a column with the Project Start Date and a column with a date that is 10 days later. Perfect. But, how do I store those new results in my existed General Project Info table and have them appear in the form? I'm obviously a beginner and am missing something.

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Oh, I am using Access 2007.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the After Update event for Project Start Date on your form to update the Project End Date control to Project Start Date + 10, but if the answer is always + 10, why store the date at all? Just use your query to show the end date.

```
Private Sub StartDate_AfterUpdate()
     Me.EndDate = Me.StartDate + 10
End Sub
```

Or

```
SELECT StartDate, StartDate + 10 As EndDate FROM ATable
```

Edit

To add an After Update event, use the property sheet in form design view. Select [Event Procedure] and then click the three little dots. It will open up the code window and you can add code into the event. You will need to use the proper names for you controls, but if you type `Me.`, intellisense will help you along with names of properties, methods and controls.

[image: events]

Comment: How do I use the query results to display the proposed date?  I can't create a text box on the form and use the query as my control source, can I?

Comment: No, but does the user need to interact with the EndDate? If so, use option 1 above, if not, just display the startdate + 10 in a textbox by setting the control source to =StartDate+10. A textbox set in this way is not editable by the user. It all depends on whether the date is always startdate + 10, or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way, if forgot to mention that in my last message.  Back to the issue: The user doesn't necessarily interact with the proposed finished date.  It's merely a guideline for the user to plan and schedule other things.  So, I might just use the textbox solution with StartDate+10.  I am actually not sure what the other solution means.  Where am I suppose to enter the "Private Sub StartDate_AfterUpdate()...."  and how is this different from the first solution? Clearly a beginner here, sorry.

Comment: We all start somewhere. You can look at you form in design view and select the property sheet for the start date control. See above.